# ng-model not updating the value to object using templates

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an MVC application using Angular. I need to open various bootstrap modal in one of the application pages. for that i just wrote a simple angular service to get the template for modal from a folder called templates and load at Run-time. Everything works fine except one thing. **ng-model** is not working for check box controls and DropDownList(select) items.
service to load template:

```
var defaultPath = "/app/services/dialog/templates/";
function _loadModalTemplate(templateName) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      if (angular.isUndefined($templateCache.get(templateName))) {
      return $http.get(defaultPath + templateName).then(function (data) {
            $templateCache.put(templateName, data.data);
                 return defer.resolve();
            });
      } else {
         return $.when($templateCache.get(templateName));
      }
    return defer.promise;
      }
```

Controller

```
notebook.controller('createworkitemcontroller', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'workitemDataContext', 'common', 'options',
        function ($scope, $modalInstance, workitemDataContext, common, options) {
            $scope.activities = options.activities || [];
            $scope.activity = $scope.activities[0];        
        }]);
```

Template HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <label class="text-xs">Activity</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" data-ng-options="a.Name for a in activities" data-ng-model="activity"></select>
</div>
```

Data Binding is working fine but its not updating the property  **$scope.activity** when any change is made. Same case with checkboxes as well but working with TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if the assignment is breaking the chain of scope. Try adding your variables inside a dedicated object like `$scope.model = {activity: ...}` and see if it works. I ran into this when I started using multiple modals and controllers. Here's a fiddle I made a while back demonstrating the concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/6XDtN/

http://jsfiddle.net/6XDtN/1/

In the first one, the parent is oblivious because the child re-defined the variable, breaking the chain of scope. It isn't obvious it re-defined the variable, but there's no way to really re-assign a value without doing so.

In the second one, the complex type (i.e. an object), is not redefined, just a property is updated. Thus, the chain of scope is strong in this one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: YES! Its working not. Need to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. I've been bitten by the browser cache as well, especially in Chrome. I mainly develop using incognito mode for this reason.